# wrong result while comparing two columns of a dataframes in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

These are my dataframes.

```
df contains no values onlly column names,

P1  |P2 |P3



df4,

    Names   Std
0   Kumar   10
1   Ravi    5



mask=df4["Names"].str.contains(('|').join(df["P1"].values.tolist()),na=False)

Out[30]:
 0    True
 1    True
Name: Names, dtype: bool
```

Why it is giving True value when the "P!" column does not have any value in it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT If need return `False`s for empty column, you can add condition for check if column is not [empty](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.empty.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['P1','P2','P3'])
print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [P1, P2, P3]
Index: []

df4 = pd.DataFrame({'Names':['Kumar','Ravi']})

mask=df4["Names"].str.contains(('|').join(df["P1"].values.tolist()),na=False)
mask = mask & (not df['P1'].empty)
print (mask)
0    False
1    False
Name: Names, dtype: bool
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'P1':['Kumar']}, columns=['P1','P2','P3'])
print (df)
      P1   P2   P3
0  Kumar  NaN  NaN

df4 = pd.DataFrame({'Names':['Kumar','Ravi']})

mask=df4["Names"].str.contains(('|').join(df["P1"].values.tolist()),na=False)
mask = mask & (not df['P1'].empty)
print (mask)
0     True
1    False
Name: Names, dtype: bool
```

Comment: ya, My question is why we are getting "True " when there is no match in the column

Comment: Ok, what return `print (df['P1'].values)` ?

Comment: nothing, as it does not have any values. It is an empty datacolumn with column name along

df,

P1  |P2 |P3

Comment: df["P1"].values


Out[34]:
array([], dtype=object)

Comment: I think there is problem you compare with empty string, so get all `True`s

Comment: what If I want "False " for the empty column ?

Comment: So first dataframe is like `df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['P1','P2','P3', ''])` ? There is column name with empty string?

Comment: no only 3 columns
df.columns
Index(['P1', 'P2', 'P3'], dtype='object')

Comment: So `mask = df4['Names'].str.contains('|'.join(df.columns),na=False)` does not work?

Comment: that is giving "False" but I want to compare only one particular column

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45413825/dropping-cell-if-it-is-nan-in-a-dataframe-in-python
can you check this one

Comment: pls check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46907847/analyzing-a-dataframe-based-on-multiple-conditions?noredirect=1#comment80762432_46907847

Comment: hi, @Jezrael, can you check this one  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47012242/how-to-create-a-dataframe-to-generate-json-in-the-given-format?noredirect=1#comment80972199_47012242