# how to create a dataframe to generate json in the given format

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, to-json

I need to generate a json from my dataframe but I have tried many formats of df but still I am not able get the required json format.

My required json format is,

```
[
    {
        "Keyword": "Red", 
        "values": [
            {
                "value": 5, 
                "TC": "Color"
            }            
        ]
    }, 
     {
        "Keyword": "Orange", 
        "values": [
            {
                "value": 5, 
                "TC": "Color"
            }            
        ]
    }, 
     {
        "Keyword": "Violet", 
        "values": [
            {
                "value": 5, 
                "TC": "Color"
            }            
        ]
    }
]
```

I want a df to generate this json. Please help.

but currently im getting df.to_json:

```
 {"Names":{"0":"Ram","1":"pechi","2":"Sunil","3":" Ravi","4":"sri"},"Values":{"0":"[{'value':2,'TC': 'TC Count'}]","1":"[{'value':2,'TC': 'TC Count'}]","2":"[{'value':1,'TC': 'TC Count'}]","3":"[{'value':1,'TC': 'TC Count'}]","4":"[{'value':1,'TC': 'TC Count'}]"}}
```

Comment: A function or set of functions that turns your dataframe onto this kind of json maybe, but "a dataframe to generate that json", no. 
I'm pretty sure it exists on the internet, something like "from dataframe to json" on Google.

Comment: ya there is a method df.to_json but I am not able to get this json. I am in need of a df to generate a json with the above format

Comment: What's the output of df.to_json ?

Comment: above json in my question is my desired_df.to_json ,help me to create my deisred_df

Comment: You're not answering my question but anyway : try `[df.to_json]` or `list(df.to_json)`

Comment: ill generate my df_to_json.

Comment: I don't understand your comment

Comment: Edited my question with my current df.to_json please check

Comment: This isn't the same data bro...

Comment: can you tell me what is the need for this question, I doubt you misread the question

Comment: The need is a bit more explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need:

- [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for columns not in nested `dictionaries`
- create dicts by `apply` with [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html)
- [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for column from index
- create json by [`to_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html)

---

```
print (df)

  Keyword     TC  value
0     Red  Color      5
1  Orange  Color      5
2  Violet  Color      5
```

```
j = (df.set_index('Keyword')
        .apply(lambda x: [x.to_dict()], axis=1)
        .reset_index(name='values')
        .to_json(orient='records'))
print (j)

[{"Keyword":"Red","values":[{"TC":"Color","value":5}]},
 {"Keyword":"Orange","values":[{"TC":"Color","value":5}]},
 {"Keyword":"Violet","values":[{"TC":"Color","value":5}]}]
```

For write to `file`:

```
(df.set_index('Keyword')
   .apply(lambda x: [x.to_dict()], axis=1)
   .reset_index(name='values')
   .to_json('myfile.json', orient='records'))
```

Comment: but when I am writing the df to new json file 

df.to_json   I am getting the below error,


AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_json'

Comment: You need change `.to_json(orient='records')` to `.to_json(filename.json, orient='records')`

Comment: I changed but still same error,

`AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-203-af1b7d67a607> in <module>()
----> 1 df_graph.to_json("G:\\json_df.json",orient='records')

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_json'` and also my type of df is ,

`is str

Comment: Your input dataframe is like in my answer?

Comment: yes the same one but after performing `df = (df.set_index('Keyword')
        .apply(lambda x: [x.to_dict()], axis=1)
        .reset_index(name='values')
        .to_json(orient='records'))` my df changed to str after that im writing it to json

Comment: Hmmm, do you use last version of pandas? Because for me it working nice :(

Comment: are you a freelancer @Jezrael

Comment: No, not, I am working in full job, but I have some time for answering ;)

Comment: I followed your solution one by one, first i did set index with keyword column for df, then i reset_index(name="Values"). But i am gettin `TypeError: reset_index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'`

Comment: Then use `reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'Values')`, if need rename new index called `index`

Comment: If new column is called something like `level_1`, need change `reset_index().rename(columns={'level_1':'Values')`.

Comment: but you used Set_index(), then a reset index () how come that works

Comment: I have one more json file similar to this question, I tried the same solution. But I am getting in a different format. could you please check when you're free https://pastebin.com/3Jkjzp8P

Comment: It is nested :( More complicated. I have idea - Can you create new question with sample dataframe, desired json output and what you try (e.g. this answer solution) ? Because with guesing data it is really hard.

Comment: But dont forget for input data ;)

Comment: here is the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47016779/creating-df-to-generate-json-in-the-given-format

Comment: Yes, but there is no input data :( Or need generate json to datafarme?

Comment: I have got only this json, creating df is my question like this above question

Comment: I need to generate that json but my question is the required df to generate that json

Comment: As you said, I edited the question with the input data, pls check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47016779/creating-df-to-generate-json-in-the-given-format