# how to remove 0's in a datacolumn in a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a df,

```
 dff=pd.DataFrame({"Name":["sri","kumar","raj"],"values":[1,0,0]})


    Name    values
    sri     1
    kumar   0
    raj     0
```

I am trying to replace 0 with spaces " "

I tried,

```
  dff["values"].astype(str).replace(0," ")
```

but still the values are same

my desired df,

```
    Name    values
    sri     1
    kumar   " "
    raj     " "
```

Comment: If you're doing an astype, then `0` has to be a string: `dff["values"].astype(str).replace("0"," ")`. Note that you don't really have to convert to a string to replace.

Comment: I tried but still it is not changed

Comment: @coldspeed, can you pls check this one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47016779/creating-df-to-generate-json-in-the-given-format

Comment: You have to assign it back to `dff['values']`.

Comment: Sorry, I'll have to pass. Have no idea how to solve that.

Answer (score 4):

You can use following

```
DataFrame.replace(
        to_replace=None,
        value=None,
        inplace=False,
        limit=None,
        regex=False, 
        method='pad',
        axis=None)
```

In your case,

```
dff['values'].replace(
    to_replace=[0],
    value=' ',
    inplace=True
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `integer` `0` or `string` `'0'`, because `astype(str)` convert `integer`s to `string`s:

```
dff["values"] = dff["values"].replace(0," ")
```

Or:

```
dff["values"] = dff["values"].astype(str).replace('0'," ")
```

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**
Use `astype(bool)` in `pd.Series.where`

```
dff.assign(values=dff['values'].where(dff['values'].astype(bool), ''))

    Name values
0    sri      1
1  kumar       
2    raj
```

---

**Option 2**
Reconstruct with `np.where`

```
pd.DataFrame(np.where(dff.eq(0), '', dff), dff.index, dff.columns)

    Name values
0    sri      1
1  kumar       
2    raj
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
In [40]: dff.ix[dff['values']==0, 'values'] = ' '

In [41]: dff
Out[41]: 
    Name values
0    sri      1
1  kumar       
2    raj
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
import pandas as pd
dff=pd.DataFrame({"Name":["sri","kumar","raj"],"values":[1,0,0]})
dff['values'].loc[dff['values']==0]='" "'
```